# wordpress+docker+apache mod proxy redirects to http://localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, docker, mod-proxy

My environment is, a docker container running wordpress on apache can be accessed via `ip:port` . The host environment has an apache instance which redirects traffic that comes to `http://myurl` to `localhost:port` using mod proxy (I have the same set up with other docker containers in the same host which is working fine). But accessing `http://myurl` (after changing the wordpress config) will just redirect you to localhost (in the wordpress container's apache log i can see it giving a 301 to redirect you) .

The problem is only there when you access the base url. (http://myurl/wp-login.php works)

Host Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.url.com
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass         /   http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /   http://localhost:8080/
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works (in `wp-config.php`):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://8.8.8.8:8080');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://8.8.8.8:8080');
```

This doesn't

```
define('WP_HOME','http://my.url.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://my.url.com');
```

These are the wordpress plugins i have enabled. But note that i changed their configs accordingly as well.

1. wp-support-plus
2. admin custom login

UPDATE:
This seems to have fixed the problem somewhat.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://8.8.8.8:8080');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://my.url.com');
```

Some of the components (home buttons etc) still go for the `ip:port` but the system works.

Comment: Ok, this is obviously issue with the docker version of Wordpress. I just spent hours trying to fix this damn issue and ended up extracting the database and the contents of the wp-content folder and then recreating the wordpress without the bloody docker.

Comment: @IvicaPesovski I fixed this issue using the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem is the headers being stripped when the redirection happens. I fixed this by adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` to the host apache configuration. The changed file looks like this now.

Host Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.url.com
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On # needed if you need to pass the original host header
ProxyPass         /   http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /   http://localhost:8080/
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out over this.  Thank you @Sudh33ra